# Converting bytes to an image with base64 via PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, base64, pyqt5

I've converted a png file  like this with base64

```
b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlz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\nAAAASUVORK5CYII=\n'
```

I have a GUİ to convert this code to and image again but when I enter it and take it with `.toPlainText()` it turns nothing.

[image]

It works if I manually type in the script:
[image]

How can I define a variable to fix that?

Comment: @ekhumoro I added :)

Comment: How do you add the text, do you use setTex(), append() or do you paste it directly through the GUI?

Comment: @eyllanesc I manually copied and then paste it on the screen. Then I take whole code with  .toPlainText()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `toPlainTex()` returns a string that in reality must be a `bytearray`, a way to convert it is using `ast.literal()` as I show below:

```
import ast

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("convert")
        lay.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

    def on_clicked(self):
        text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        try:
            data = ast.literal_eval(text)
            ba = QtCore.QByteArray.fromBase64(data)
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
            if pixmap.loadFromData(ba, "PNG"):
                self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        except SyntaxError:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `QByteArray.fromBase64()` was throwing an error because it expects a byte array not a string. Instead I used `base64.b64decode()`.